# Tensor Product, proof of isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

Let V and W be two vector spaces and

$$\Phi: Hom_K(\land^rV,W)\rightarrow Alt_K^r(V,W)\\ f \mapsto [(v_1,....,v_r)\mapsto f(v_1\land \cdot \cdot \cdot \land v_r)]$$

I need to show that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism.

I know we can define two bilinear maps but how would we show that they this map is isomorphic?

Comment: This is the definition of $\wedge^r V$ using universal property.

Comment: What is $\bigwedge^r V$ for you? (An answer like “the $r$-th exterior power of $V$” doesn’t tell me anything.)

Comment: @Q.Zhang This is the definition of $\land^r V$?

Comment: @azif00 Then i wouldnt have any idea. What you wrote is literally the definition that i was given

Comment: Usually, the definition goes like this: *The $r$-th exterior power of $V$ is a vector space $\bigwedge^r V$ together with an alternating multilinear map $\wedge \colon \prod_r V \to \bigwedge^r V$, denoted as $v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_r := \wedge(v_1,\dots,v_r)$, with the following property: **For any** other space $W$, and any **alternating multilinear map** $g \colon \prod_r V \to W$, **there exists a unique linear map** $\tilde g \colon \bigwedge^r V \to W$ **such that** $g = \tilde g \circ \wedge$*. Now, how is this related with the map $\Phi \colon f \mapsto f \circ \wedge$?

Comment: @azif00         ouh that definition confuses me a bit, isn't $v_1 \land ... \land v_r$ the same as $\land (v_1,...v_r)$?           all thou can i use the multilinear map $\land$ and the alternating mulitilinear map $g$ defined as you have, and show that are inverses of eachother and therefore $\Phi$ is an isomorphism?